# Why won't Terraria open?

Tags: terraria-mobile

On Terraria, when I open the app, it shows the supporters and stuff. Then when it gets to the title screen and I press "play", the game freezes and then exits out of the app. This was right after the new version of Terraria came out. (Easter update 2015 I think.) I double tap the home button and exits out of all my apps that are open. I retry to go on Terraria, but the same thing happens. I clear my one app that is open (Terraria). I then rebooted my iPad mini. I tried to get into Terraria again but it won't work. I will not delete the app and ALL of my iCloud storage is taken up, so that isn't a choice. Is there any way at all to fix this?

Comment: You could try something [like this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39102/can-i-reinstall-a-single-ios-app-without-losing-its-data) (<- link) to backup the Terraria data to allow you to reinstall it without losing your save.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Relogic support (they made Terraria). The email is: support@re-logic.com What version of iOS do you have?

Answer (score 1):

My way of fixing this problem was, Close all apps, shut down device, leave for 24 hours, open the device, go into a seperate app, be on that for about 10 minutes, go on Terraria and that worked for me.